# Why is an Azure permission missing from the scopes of my JWT token?

Tags: azure, permissions, jwt, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a problem regarding the permission granted to my app by the user showing up as a scope in my JWT.

I want to allow the user to see a list of his tenants (Office 365) on my page. For this I need a token with the `https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation` scope. I added the permission to the Azure API Permissions. When the user first logs in he sees this:

[image: permission request]

From this screen I assume my setup works, since the user gets asked to grant my app permission for what I need (Access Azure Service Management as you). But when I paste the JWT on [the JWT Debugger](https://jwt.io/) I don't see the scope `user_impersonation` among the scopes.

I get this:

[image: scp variable value]

I already tried to remove the app from the test-user's applications (in their Azure Portal) to get it to ask again for consent but it's still the same. Other test users have also the same result.
What I'd need is simply to see `user_impersonation` among the scopes. That would allow me to call the API endpoint that returns a list of my user's tenants.

Comment: Sorry for the images, but I don't have enough Stack Overflow reputation to post them.

Comment: You need to acquire the token for the `https://management.azure.com` resource I think. That looks like an MS Graph API token.

Comment: Or with that full scope name if you are using v2

Comment: How do you mean? I already have https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation in my scopes, you can also see it as the first permission on my first screenshot. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Somewhere in your code you acquire the access token. An access token is only valid for one API, and the one you are showing is an access token for MS Graph API. Thus it won't contain the scope for Azure Management API. So when you acquire the token, you need to specify that you want a token for the Azure Management API, and not MS Graph API.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I could get both API's scopes in one token. I made a separate call for both API's and now it works! Thanks a lot!

I will update my post to make your answer more visible.

Comment: @juunas, you should post your comment as an answer, that way I can mark it as one and you'll get the karma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to acquire the access token for the `https://management.azure.com` resource.
Or if using v2, request it for the `https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation` scope.

That looks like an MS Graph API token.

An access token is always only valid for one API, so you need to ask for a token for the Azure Management API.

Answer (score 0):

It works now!

So, I tried to get scopes for both https://management.azure.com/ and https://graph.microsoft.com/ in one single token. As [Juunas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1658906/juunas) explained, you have to get a separate token for each API. But can ask consent for both at the same time though.

My flow is this now:

1. I log the user in while asking him to consent to some permissions (for both API's and on first login only)
2. I request a token in the background for the Graph API scopes
3. I request a second token for the Azure Management API scopes

Comment: Hi, in step 1, you got the authorization code and with that authorization code you can request for the Graph API scopes thats OK. However, how you can use same authorization code again for the Azure Management API? I know that authorization codes only for one time usage.